# How to give permission for a custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Situation is, I have a Library that can be updated by each and every user in that site but from that users, only one person have permission to view all the documents and others can get the full permission(include to see) for their documents only. so how to give the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give all the users contribute permissions on the library so that they can contribute to it and make give full control to one user. Next Go to list settings , advanced settings Item level permissions and check **Read items that were created by the user**